# cite configure in tex4ht

Tags: bibliographies, citing, tex4ht

I am trying to configure the `\cite` command for the `xml` structure in

`<xref rid="cite" bibid="aa">[1]</xref>`

with the two things need to be configured:

1. In the `bibid =""` original `\cite{label id}` to be retain, How to achieve this one?
2. When I am using `cite.sty` the configure structure is printed in the HTML file
   but when using `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` the configured structured  is not printing in the HTML file? How to achieve this for `natbib.sty` also?

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

<xref rid="cite" bibid="">[1]</xref>

\begin{document}

\cite{aa}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{aa}Sample Bib text

\bibitem{ab}Sample Bib text

\bibitem{ac}Sample Bib text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

CFG

```
\Configure{cite}
   {\HCode{<xref rid="cite" bibid="">}}{\HCode{</xref>}}
   {\Link} {\EndLink}
```